# Many-to-many query selecting records with no match from the right as well as values from the left in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a standard many-to-many schema like this:

`items` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo |

`groups` table:

| id | name | slug |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | baz | qux |

`items_to_groups`:

| item_id | group_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

The `groups.slug` is used to query Group information. The ID is internal.

I need to query for `items` that are not in a specified `group`, but also need to include the `group` attributes (like `name`) in the result set.

The query is trivial without the need for values from the `groups` table, but I cannot figure out how to include them.

Here is my best attempt:

```
SELECT
    g.slug,
    g.name,
    i.name
FROM
    items AS i
    LEFT JOIN items_to_groups AS itg ON i.id = itg.item_id
    LEFT JOIN groups AS g ON itg.group_id = g.id
    AND g.slug = 'group-slug-1'
WHERE
    itg.item_id IS NULL;
```

Results:

```
||Item name 1
||Item name 2
```

Desired results:

```
group-slug-1|1|Item name 1
group-slug-1|1|Item name 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking:

```
select i.*, g.*
from items i cross join
     groups g
where g.slug = 'group-slug-1' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from items_to_groups ig
                  where ig.item_id = i.id and ig.group_id = g.id
                 );
```